# How to install WordPress on root domain and Php script on subdomain?

Tags: installation

I have built a website using WordPress. I installed WordPress on root domain i.e www.example.com . Now I want to install a Php Script based website on subdomain  and subdirectories i.e subdomain.example.com and www.example.com/subdirectory.
I know it is possible to do this but I need the working process to make it possible. If anyone know this then please guide me.

Comment: You need to do it using your webserver's configuration. What webserver are you using? `Apache` / `Nginx`?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress supports multi-sites setup for both sub-domain and subdirectory approach, please take a look at [Create a Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

Comment: I know about wordpress multisites but here I'm asking about Installing Php Script on subdomain and WordPress on root

Comment: So your so-called 'php scripted based' website means a non-wordpress site? In that case, you may need to create two VirtualHost directives on server level (Apache or Nginx, depend which one you are using), something like `<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
</VirtualHost>` for site1, and 
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site2/"
</VirtualHost>` for site2

Comment: Yes, it is non wordpress website. Are u telling me to create two separate directories in var/www/html folder? If yes then what to do after that?

Comment: You need to create two virtual host configurations at your server. Since the topic is not related to Wordpress, I don't want to post it here. But you could take a look at [this link](http://serverfault.com/questions/146550/how-to-set-up-multiple-websites-virtual-hosts-on-mamp) or search more on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) or check with your hosting company. Please noted that my example of /var/www/html/ is an example for typical apache server root directory, you need to check your actual hosting environment for your root directory.